# git: Conflict upon merging back a cherry-picked commit

Tags: git

I've made a commit A to a branch bugfix, cherry picked that commit
into branch develop. Then I made a change B to the bugfix branch
touching the areas of the code around those made in commit A.
Now when I merged origin/develop back into the branch bugfix
git has indicated conflict around those lines.
Is that an error in git or is that intentional by design?
I mean: the changes that caused the faux conflict originated
on the bugfix branch and that very branch ALREADY HAD commit A.

Comment: No, something is wrong. Considering you created your `bugfix` branch from `develop` right before committing A, and no commits were done except A and B, this should apply cleanly. I assume those files were already different before your commits, or changed after (pull from remote before merge, for example).

Comment: yes, I've branched off develop a few days back and they've been diverging ever since. But the cherry pick of commit A to develop has made the two files in question identical.

Comment: So you answered your own question. Use this to see why it happened: `git diff bugfix_B_SHA develop_A_SHA -- file.c`.

Comment: So merge does not really care if a branch already has a commit coming back as a cherry pick from another branch? Manuel Schmidt claims that "Unlike when you merge, a cherry-picked commit is not the same commit anymore" then it makes sense that git tries to merge back again a commit that branch already possess.

Comment: You're right @Anton , git tries to merge the cherry-picked commit since it's a new commit not yet contained in the branch

Comment: Ok, I now see the point. @Manuelschmidt is probably right.

Comment: As I say in my answer, you shouldn't think of merge as merging all the commits of each branch - merging two branches essentially means merging the two last commits of each branch into one new commit. Remember that a branch in Git is nothing else than a pointer to a commit, and a commit is a chain of all previous commits in the DAG.

Comment: yeah, gotta find the time to read the freaking git documentation to understand the fundamentals and the fallout from fundamentals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike when you merge, **a cherry-picked commit is not the same commit anymore, but a new commit** that contains the same changes (look at the hash of the cherry picked commit and campare it with the original one). Thus, changes on the code affected by the cherry-picked commit, in any of your two branches, will result in a merge conflict when you finally merge both branches together. Actually, for Git it is as if you have done the changes in an independent way on your two branches and in a different way (since you changed the code of the cherry-picked commit afterwards).

If you don't change the code affected by the cherry pick in any of the two branches before merging them finally together, git will see two different commits, but with exactly the same changes. In this case no merge conflict will be shown.

Please note, that a commit is more than only the changes it contains. It's also the date you have done the changes, the commit message, the parent commit, etc. This is way a new commit is created.

This is why you should avoid using cherry-picks if there are other ways achieving what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A conflict simply indicates that the code at the tip of branch A conflicts with the code at the tip of branch B. If the changes you have done in your bugfix branch "conflicts" with the changes initially done in the cherry-picked commit you will have resolve those changes.

> I mean: the changes that caused the faux conflict originated on the
>   bugfix branch and that very branch ALREADY HAD commit A.

But you also say that you have done more changes in the bugfix branch? That code is not in develop, thus the conflict...