# Moving commits from source branch, but keeping them when target branch will be merged back in?

Tags: git

We starting developing a feature in the dev branch but realized it was going to take much longer, so we created a feature branch in the middle of development for the remaining changes.

The commits are not contiguous in the dev branch. We would like to revert those commits on the dev branch for preparation of a release without any of the feature branch code.

We have this:

```
A--Fa--B--Fb--C--D--E--F--G   <-- dev
               \
                Fc--Fd--Fe    <-- feature
```

We want this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G   <-- dev
 \
  Fa--Fb--Fc--Fd--Fe  <-- feature
```

And this is easily possible via reverting the `Fa`, `Fb` commits on the dev branch. But, when the time comes to merge the feature branch in, will git complain?

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--   <-- dev
 \                  /
  Fa--Fb--Fc--Fd--Fe        <-- feature
```

The answer [appears to be yes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690980/375399)... and I wonder if there's a way to avoid that?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22461088/git-cherry-picked-feature-commits-into-new-branch-reverted-commits-rebase-no) is almost exactly what I am asking -- but my commits are not contiguous. Does that matter?

I cannot (easily) rewrite the history--but I suppose it's possible (only 2 other devs have the repository).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after playing with git a bit, the only option was to revert the commits, reset the dev branch, and recommit everything since (including non-feature work) as one giant blob, force push and then merging would sort-of work better down the line.

It was just easier to comment out a few lines to make the code dead.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can hard reset your dev branch to commit A. Then you can start a new feature branch there, then cherry pick the appropriate commits for both the branches. When you are done cherry picking the commits, delete the old feature branch. I think you will elegantly achieve the state that you want.